# What makes LINQ (C#) unique compared to another DSL such as Django query syntax?

Tags: c#, django, linq

### My question to the community is this:

What makes C#'s LINQ Unique from other query language in other languages and frameworks, or does it not have anything to make it unique at this point?

Specifically with regard to Django or Laravel, but that doesn't matter all that much. I'm not looking for an opinion of why someone might like it more but rather if there is any concrete difference between them that a general developer would be inclined to choose one over the other because of that difference.

### Thoughts

Before I posted this I found this SE post ([Python Unique Characteristics](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/127669/what-are-some-characteristics-of-python-that-makes-it-unique-as-its-own-language)), that talks about it may be rather hard to find something that is actually unique. Which is a valid point, however the reason I ask is because I know a lot of .NET developers that use LINQ as a main selling point of .NET (myself included). However, when thinking about it more in depth I don't know if it is a valid argument anymore which is more what I'm trying to accomplish with this question.

### What follows is context

My coworker and I were debating on the reason why LINQ (in the context of C#) could be an argument to use C# over another language. Especially when it can be compared to other DSLs like it (At least I believe it's a kind of DSL, could be wrong though). We could not actually think of any concrete reason why LINQ would have any distinct advantage, feature or unique oddity over any other query syntax in a modern language or framework. The closest I could come up with was that you could write an underlying driver for LINQ to allow it to theoretically work with just about any data system out there, but the argument could me made that other languages support stuff like that as well.

Part of this question is due to an on going internal discussion between our devs about the merits of C# vs Django, but that is an entirely other area not for the scope of this question.

### General Information

The following are some locations where I have been looking to try and find information at least from more official sources.

- [Laravel query documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries)
- [LINQ Documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/)
- [Django query Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What makes LINQ (C#) unique compared to another DSL such as Django query syntax?

Simply put: what makes C# Language INtegrated Queries unique is that it is a Query Language that is Integrated into the Language.

"Django query syntax" in comparison is not integrated into the language. In fact, it is not syntax *at all*. It's just method calls into a library. It does not change the syntax or semantics of the Python language.

Whether or not that is an advantage is irrelevant, since that is not the question. The question is what makes it unique. (Well, not totally unique since Visual Basic.NET has the same thing.)

LINQ also happens to be LINM (Language INtegrated Monads), which in *my* opinion is the *much more interesting* part of LINQ, but Haskell and Scala have that as well, so it is not really unique.

Comment: "not syntax at all" - not quite, might be more accurate to say it's not python syntax/the syntax of the host language

Answer (score 3):

While Linq is certainly an attractive feature to consider on its own merits, the real value of Linq is all of the other powerful language features that were added to the C# language and framework that make Linq possible:

1. Expression Trees
2. Lambda Expressions
3. Extension Methods
4. The `var` keyword
5. Type inference
6. Linq providers

And probably other features that I haven't thought of.

Comment: Would 4 and 5 not effectively be the same? I was under the impression that var was C#'s version of type inference as auto is in C++. I suppose var is just the keyword that states to use type inference, perhaps.

Comment: @KaydenMiller Type inference is included in quite a few other C# features too, including generic method arguments, lambda arguments and array initialisers